# How can I pull 12 million rows into CSV from hive table using Java faster?

Tags: csv, jdbc, hive

I need to pull ~12million rows into CSV using JDBC to Hive Connection. Can I do it faster using some batch processing? Can I append the CSV file?

I have made the connection to Hive using JDBC and I am able to create the CSV file in my local machine. But it runs really long because of large number of rows. I am using the JDBC result Set to store the query results and write it to the CSV using FileWriter and CSVWriter class of Java.

I want to speed up the process to copy data into CSV. I am looking for some kind of batch processing way to read data from table and append it to the CSV.

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 1):

[Univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) dumps resultsets into CSV pretty easily:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");

//configure your CSV format
CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = Csv.writeExcel(); //pre-configured format to be excel compatible
writerSettings.setHeaderWritingEnabled(true); // if you want the column names to be printed out in the first row

CsvRoutines routines = new CsvRoutines(writerSettings);
routines.write(resultSet, new File("/path/to/your.csv"), "windows-1252");
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library (Apache 2.0 license)